# IPython 'application/json' support is not working

Tags: json, ipython, mime-types, jupyter-notebook

I'm upgrading my IPython kernel for apache spark to support multiple MIME types. While every other types including 'text/html' & 'text/latex' works perfectly fine. The 'application/json' failed in all case:

The websocket response from my kernel looks like this:

{"parent_header":{"username":"username","msg_id":"58FD3A37DA264BBA86BEDC6E006A2AE1","session":"3D296AF47B6546C7ACC9072150B5AD20","msg_type":"execute_request"},"msg_type":"pyout","msg_id":"3c11053a-be86-4086-a606-01fb9eddeb26","content":{"execution_count":1,"data":{"application/json":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"},"metadata":{}},"header":{"username":"username","msg_id":"3c11053a-be86-4086-a606-01fb9eddeb26","session":"3D296AF47B6546C7ACC9072150B5AD20","msg_type":"pyout"},"metadata":{}}

But the output (both commandline & notebook) shows nothing. Can anyone explain why it is listed as 'supported' in official IPython 2.3 document but can't be displayed

Comment: JSON is a data format, not really a display format. So IPython supports publishing it, but you need to do something on the frontend to listen for and display json data. If you just want to display raw JSON, use mime type `text/plain`.

Comment: Understand, its not supported by standard IPy frontend but may be supported by its extension. Is it right

Comment: Yes, a frontend extension should be able to listen for it and display it. Or just display JSON as text if you only want to see the raw JSON.